# Problem Setting VM Arguments with Eclipse 3.5.2

Tags: eclipse

I upgraded my Eclipse application from 3.4.1 to 3.5.2 and up until this point, I had no problems.
What I'm experiencing now has to do with the VM arguments.  I'm trying to set them in the main plugin's `*.product` file, under the "Launching" tab as such:

```
-DSTANDALONE -Xmx500M -Duser.dir=${project_loc}/..
```

However, instead of having `user.dir` set to the right value, it's always equal to `/..`, meaning that Eclipse isn't substituting its `project_loc` variable in that argument.
I've also tried a number of different variables there, including `ProjDirPath`, and not a single variable gets substituted properly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg17176.html):

> `${ProjDirPath}` is not a generic Eclipse substitution variable. It is usable only in the context of the CDT build system.

In 3.4.1, as illustrated by [bug 227591](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=227591#c6),  `${project_loc}` was still referenced by `debug.ui`, before being moved to `debug.core`.

> when a variable like `${project_loc}` is reference without an argument, the resolution will also resolve the value of ${selected_resource_path}, else it can perform the resolution without the selected resource.
>
> So, when a variable is not qualified with an argument, it still requires the
>   UI, but the variables can be used headless when arguments are specified.

In your case, did you try with an argument?

```
${project_loc:/MyProject}
```

> The latter variant uses the argument and interprets it as a workspace-relative path. No selection is required. It is save to evaluate on any thread.